# Rails collection_select not working but equivalent select with options_from_collection_for_select does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, merge, nomethoderror

Here is my code snippet that works exactly as intended:

```
<%= f.select(:other_model_id, 
             options_from_collection_for_select(
               OtherModel.all, 
               :id, 
               :full_name,
               { :selected => @this_model.other_model_id} )) %>
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work:

```
<%= f.collection_select :this_model, :other_model_id, 
                         OtherModel.all, :id, :full_name %>
```

There error I get is:

> undefined method `merge' for :full_name:Symbol

Any suggestions?  The fact that :full_name works properly with the working code leads me to believe I screwed up the syntax in the simplified collection_select code and that the problem is not elsewhere.

Comment: Try adding `()` for the args. Else try adding a last param as `{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mixing up two different `collection_select` methods. You're calling the [`FormBuilder#collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select) using the [`FormOptionsHelper#collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) arguments. Maybe you want this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :other_model_id, OtherModel.all, :id, :full_name %>
```

Or perhaps this:

```
<%= collection_select :this_model, :other_model_id, OtherModel.all, :id, :full_name %>
```

You end up trying to put `:full_name` in the `options` argument but that's supposed to be a Hash, that's where the complaint about "no `merge` method" comes from.

Comment: Yep, dropping the :this_model as the first argument did the trick.